# CLLocationManager strange behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I am using location manager to get user location when he/she presses a button.

I just need that exat time location, so I turn off the updates after I get the location.

The thing if that the location I am getting id 0 lat 0 lng at the first time.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    lng = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"New Latlng: %f x %f", lat, lng);
}
```

When the user presses the button I call: [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

And right after that I send the location to my server [self sendData]. But the location is zero.
At my -sendData method I added an NSLog to track down what was going on and I realized that I was sending the data to the server before the -locationManager:didUpdateToLocation gets called...

```
2012-04-02 16:06:24.225 MyApp[2892:707] ---- Data sent to server ----
2012-04-02 16:06:25.167 MyApp[2892:707] Nova Latlng: -23.003582 x -43.316311
```

I tried this but it didnt work as expected either:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self sendData];
    });
});
```

How to make the [self sendData] wait until I have the lat and lng variables properly filled?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you make that call right after you `stopUpdatingLocation` ?

Comment: The delegate still gets called at least 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self sendData];
});
```

in `didUpdateToLocation:` after

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

That should do it. The Location Manager updates come asynchronously, so you have to wait until there is something to process before you try to do anything with the data.

Comment: by doing that, the sendData method gets called 3 times... do you know why?

Comment: Could be that `didUpdateToLocation:` is getting called that many times BEFORE the line of code that stops updates is called once. Add a static boolean to that method so you can know if you sent the data once or not, and only send if the bool is NO.